# NextJS show error overlay in other environments than local development

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to show the error overlay of NextJS in other environments except production.

Currently it only shows up in local development and I would like to show it in others like ("development" - it's different than local & "uat")

What I've tried so far without a result is:

1. Changed `next.config.js` like so

```
webpack(config, { dev }) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
    });

    if(!dev) {
      config.devtool = "source-map";
    }

    return config;
  }
```

1. Importing / requiring `react-error-overlay` in root
2. Modifying the webpack like so

```
const ErrorOverlayPlugin = require('error-overlay-webpack-plugin');
...
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { dev }) => {
    if (dev) {
      // Add the error overlay plugin only in development
      config.plugins.push(new ErrorOverlayPlugin());
    }

    return config;
  },
};
```